# "neither/nor" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was wondering if the use of "neither/nor" is correct and comprehensible in the sentence:

*Moreover, most probably neither was the snake linked to Cleopatra because of the erotic association nor the cat assigned to her because she was a voluptuous witch.*

Comment: I suppose the sentence is grammatical but it is very hard to read. I suggest a complete re-write.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I agree but at least the *neither...nor* construction is correctly applied, which is what the question was about.

Comment: Thx a lot! Actually, it's my translation of a piece of quite a serious scientific text. Equally hard to read in the original ;-) Could you suggest a way to rewrite it?

Comment: Done. See my answer.

Comment: I think your sentence wold benefit from adding "was" after "nor", to make the "nor" clause grammatically parallel to the "neither" clause.

Comment: @shogun why were the snake and cat linked to Cleopatra?  Don't leave us wondering!  Or is it too long to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use of *neither* is at best marginally grammatical. It is certainly extremely rare: all the examples of *Neither do/does* that I looked at in GlowBE (the Corpus of Global Web English) are "afterthought" - following a negative statement

> He doesn't want to. Neither do I.

rather than "forethought"

> ? Neither does he want to nor do I.

(It's not even clear to me whether to invert the subject and verb in this construction or not: *?Neither he wants to nor do I*.)

With other coordinates (noun phrases, prepositional phrases, verbs, or verb phrases) it is fine:

> I want neither tea nor coffee.
>
> I do it neither at home nor at work.
>
> I neither wanted nor asked for this.
>
> I neither rang the bell nor waited for them.

It's just full sentences where it doesn't occur. This is also true for the other forethought connector, *both ... and*.

> I both rang the bell and waited.

but probably not

> ? Both did I ring the bell and I waited.

Comment: Ok. How about this way: Moreover, most probably, the snake was not linked to Cleopatra because of the erotic association, neither was the cat assigned to her because she was a voluptuous witch.

Comment: @shogun, that is what I called the _afterthought_ use: just with an asyndetic clause rather than a separate sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the sentence is grammatical but I find it very hard to read.

A possible paraphrase would be:

*Moreover, it was probably neither true that the snake was linked to Cleopatra because of the erotic association, nor that the cat was assigned to her because she was a voluptuous witch.*

Comment: Thx again. I guess your re-write reads clearer indeed ;-)

Comment: Or maybe this: "Moreover, in all likelihood, the linking of the snake to Cleopatra was not a result of the erotic association, nor was the assigning of the cat to her due to her being a voluptuous witch." In reality, of course, the linking of the snake to Cleopatra was by the snake's fangs.