# Neither-nor, usage of neither-nor with verb

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, conjunctions, compounds, neither-nor

Which one is correct?
**1. Neither anything changed nor we were informed.**
**2. Neither changed anything nor were we informed.**

Comment: This is a fairly meaningless question. Given the correct *context*, both sequences are syntactically fine. But note that #1 isn't a valid ***sentence*** - as it stands, it's just a verb clause without a subject.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. As your question stands, it is a request for proofreading (which is off topic, and therefore likely to be closed). Which one do you think is correct? Which one have you encountered before? Please state your research into which one you think is correct and why.

Answer (score 1):

Neither ... nor ... constructions must be balanced.

- Neither John nor Ali was to blame..... Neither *John* nor *Ali* was to blame.
- We saw neither Alice nor Farzana..... We saw neither *Alice* nor *Farzana*.
- The bat is neither fish nor fowl..... The bat is neither *fish* nor *fowl*.
- I neither saw nor heard the explosion..... I neither *saw* nor *heard* the explosion.
- He neither saw the crowd nor heard the shouting..... He neither *saw the crowd* nor *heard the shouting*.

When neither starts the sentence and the verbs differ, it's almost certain that either **passives** or do-support must be used (so neither example above is a valid sentence):

- Neither was Jack charged nor Jill released.

However, this sounds at best old-fashioned and very formal. And according to @Colin Fine at a related thread ([Neither-nor in a {Neither was A V1-d nor B V2-d}sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262982/neither-nor-in-a-sentence)), even with two passives these sentences are *marginally grammatical*.

Less contentious, perhaps, is a sentence using **do-support** (probably with deletion of the second *do*):

- Neither do the sons ever return to their homeland nor the bereaved mothers cease their weeping.

This is even more archaic and literary in register.